# Running TestNg tests via JUnit TestSuite

Tags: junit, testng

Is it possible to execute TestNg tests in a JUnit TestSuite. I see a lot of web pages describing how to use TestNg to run JUnit but none the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

No, only JUnit tests can be run in TestNG.

TestNG was initially developed as a replacement for JUnit with additional functionality and an emphasis on smooth migration. An ability to run JUnit tests was one of the tools for that smooth migration.

TestNG fully covers the functionality of JUnit and adds something new. And JUnit can not (currently?) emulate that difference in functionality.

You may check the comparison of these two libraries [here](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-vs-testng-comparison/).